# Exception: Could not find at URL https://www.languagetool.org/download/LanguageTool-5.5.zip. language_tool_python, Mac M1

Tags: java, python-3.x, macos, mini-forge

When using **language_tool_python** package for finding gramatical errors, I found the following Exception:

`Exception: Could not find at URL https://www.languagetool.org/download/LanguageTool-5.5.zip.`

I am using Mac M1, had to install **Java 17** (tried Java 8 as well) from Azul Zulu so its recognizes Java module.

On Linux, works fine.

Seems like there is a problem with the URL, but when we go directly the file exists!

https://www.languagetool.org/download/LanguageTool-5.5.zip

Also tried version 2.5 but I got the same result.

Is there a workaround for this?

Thanks!

Here the traceback:

````
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/d_/hfs18jf54371qfmf54zq289c0000gn/T/ipykernel_33610/1177712971.py in <module>
----> 1 tool = language_tool_python.LanguageTool('en-US')

~/miniforge3/envs/transformers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/language_tool_python/server.py in __init__(self, language, motherTongue, remote_server, newSpellings)
     43             self._update_remote_server_config(self._url)
     44         elif not self._server_is_alive():
---> 45             self._start_server_on_free_port()
     46         if language is None:
     47             try:

~/miniforge3/envs/transformers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/language_tool_python/server.py in _start_server_on_free_port(self)
    179             self._url = 'http://{}:{}/v2/'.format(self._HOST, self._port)
    180             try:
--> 181                 self._start_local_server()
    182                 break
    183             except ServerError:

~/miniforge3/envs/transformers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/language_tool_python/server.py in _start_local_server(self)
    189     def _start_local_server(self):
    190         # Before starting local server, download language tool if needed.
--> 191         download_lt()
    192         err = None
    193         try:

~/miniforge3/envs/transformers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/language_tool_python/download_lt.py in download_lt(update)
    152         return
    153 
--> 154     download_zip(language_tool_download_url, download_folder)
    155 
    156 if __name__ == '__main__':

~/miniforge3/envs/transformers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/language_tool_python/download_lt.py in download_zip(url, directory)
    123     # Download file.
    124     downloaded_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.zip', delete=False)
--> 125     http_get(url, downloaded_file)
    126     # Close the file so we can extract it.
    127     downloaded_file.close()

~/miniforge3/envs/transformers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/language_tool_python/download_lt.py in http_get(url, out_file, proxies)
    104     total = int(content_length) if content_length is not None else None
    105     if req.status_code == 403: # Not found on AWS
--> 106         raise Exception('Could not find at URL {}.'.format(url))
    107     progress = tqdm.tqdm(unit="B", unit_scale=True, total=total, desc='Downloading LanguageTool')
    108     for chunk in req.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):

Exception: Could not find at URL https://www.languagetool.org/download/LanguageTool-5.5.zip.```
````

Comment: Is the trailing dot after `zip` needed?  `https://www.languagetool.org/download/LanguageTool-5.5.zip.`  returns 404 error too.

Comment: The issue has been reported in [Github](https://github.com/jxmorris12/language_tool_python/issues/48), although it seems to be solved now. Are you still facing the problem?

Comment: @AlexRudenko I tried also to go up `.../download` but got the same error 403.

Comment: @jccampanero I just tried

`req = requests.get('https://www.languagetool.org/download/LanguageTool-5.5.zip',stream=True, proxies=None)`

geting

`<Response [403]>`

Comment: Could it be something related with user agents on Safari with Mac M1? 

I'm trying on Linux Mint same code, but it works fine.

Comment: I agree with you. I obtained the same result. And I agree with @JoopEggen, if you examine the response `history` a redirect is performed.

Comment: The redirect is performed against `https://languagetool.org/download/LanguageTool-5.5.zip`. Pay attention to the url, it is not under `www` anymore. And this link returns always `403`, forbidden.

Comment: Agree, I Just post the issue in the official forum page:

https://forum.languagetool.org/t/automated-download-of-lt-does-not-work/7424

and they tell me This is a known issue, and we’re working on it. It will hopefully be fixed in a few days.

I just wonder if we can just get the local files from the languages to make it work and stop depending on the server...

Answer (score 1):

***Not an answer: the network traffic***

In the browser, development tool, network: a redirect on the zip,
For the rest tracking.

| Name | Status | Type | Initiator | Size | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| collect?v=1&_v=j96&a=421817770&t=event&_s=2&dl=htt…-languagetool-org-download-languaget&z=2037529220 | 200 | xhr | analytics.js:44 | 22 B | 211 ms |
| Pingym?gm0=0&gm1=0&tivt=2549&hov=1&tth=113&intt=2&intl…0:tp=1:mt=7&sek=3697285284406464539:1638139533389 | 200 | ping | inside.js:1 | 1.3 kB | 324 ms |
| Bilddt?advEntityId=819590&asId=ecf354bb-1855-2567-a204…13*,rmeas:1,rend:1,renddet:DIV.qs.sn,lt:0%7D&br=c | 200 | gif | dcmads.js:1011 | 216 B | 1.08 s |
| Document LanguageTool-5.5.zip | **301** | document / redirect | others | 300 B | 295 ms |
| XHRcollect?t=dc&aip=1&_r=3&v=1&_v=j96&tid=UA-10824261…7377033.1638135822&_u=SCCACEABBAAAAC~&z=905256628 | 200 | xhr | analytics.js:44 | 22 B | 195 ms |
| Document LanguageTool-5.5.zip | 200 | document | LanguageTool-5.5.zip | 11.0 kB | 494 ms |

Not sure whether the redirect is causing the problem.